# Angular binding for dynamically added html div

Tags: angularjs, jquery-load

Sorry, this seems a duplicated questions, but I tried all answered questions close to my question, with no success.

I am trying to introduce angular.js into a legacy system.
the system is using the [.load jquery](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to dynamically load div content with a page from an ASP.NET MVC page.

my brief html will look like this

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
any content...
<div id="dyncontent"> </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript legacy code looks like

```
$('#dyncontent').load('/showviewcontent');
```

I added in the dynamic content, some angular directive and binding instruction

my angular code is like this

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
.....
});
```

How to make the binding / angular directive works on the newly added content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually start the angular module using [angular.bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

```
$('#dyncontent').load('/showviewcontent', function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('dyncontent'), ['myApp']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked.
I was looking for answers, and I found answers to call $scope.$apply, and $compile, and none of them worked.
More happy to see a Calgarian helped me with this

Comment: Sorry, In case I empty that div, and reload it again, how can I re-bootstrap again.
I can bootstrap only once, and I didn't find any way to destroy the application

Comment: @gkar You would probably have to remove the dom element that you bound the application to and re-create it.